Getting an error : redefinition of struct within a .h program
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct sommet sommet;
typedef struct voisin voisin;
typedef struct graphe graphe;

struct sommet{  
    int indice;
    sommet* next;
    voisin* first_voisin;
};

struct voisin{
    int indice;
    voisin* next_voisin; 
};

struct graphe{
    sommet* premier_sommet;
}; 

Here's a simple struct definition h program.
I get an Error : redefinition of struct for each of these.
How can I fix this ?
Thanks !
I tried putting directly
typedef struct sommet {
 //code
};

and also
typedef struct{
 //code 
}sommet;


What you've shown is fine.  The problem is in the code you haven't shown.  Please update your question to include a [mcve].  That being said, my crystal ball says you're including the file more that once in a given source file.

How is used this header? Do you have multiple header (.h) and source (.c) files?

Make sure you have an include guard

Sidenote: Don't #include <stdio.h> and #include <stdlib.h> in the header file unless you need anything from those header files in your header file. By the looks of it, you don't.

Hi!  This error message tells you that once you define a struct like sommet you can mention the struct name again anytime, but you cannot re-define it again somewhere else.  By "define" we mean show it by naming all the components/members like you did the very first time.   And that is why Barmar mentions include guard -- because every module that includes the *.h file with the struct definition risks redefining the structure -- but the include guard makes sure it's only defined once.  It's best practice (not mandatory) to declare the typedef from the 1st time you define the struct, too.

Confidence is high that you can resolve your redefinition compile-time issue(s) by following best practices such as the following... please note that this code represents 2 files -- a MyHeaderFile.h and main.c.
The include guard MY_HEADER_FILE_Hat the top of MyHeaderFile.h ensures that the structure definitions (and anything else in the include file) will only be defined once, and this is key.  It tells the compiler, "Only enter past this point if MY_HEADER_FILE_H is NOT defined."  This prevents a 2nd definition of everything that follows.
Beyond that there is not much else to tell -- it is your code, after all.
Runnable code here.
/* ---------- MyHeaderFile.h ---------- */
#ifndef MY_HEADER_FILE_H
#define MY_HEADER_FILE_H

#include <stdio.h>  /* Pls see Ted Lyngmo's comment on this */
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct sommet sommet;
typedef struct voisin voisin;
typedef struct graphe graphe;

struct sommet{  
    int indice;
    sommet* next;
    voisin* first_voisin;
};

struct voisin{
    int indice;
    voisin* next_voisin; 
};

struct graphe{
    sommet* premier_sommet;
};

#endif //MY_HEADER_FILE_H

/* ---------- main.c ---------- */
#include "MyHeaderFile.h"

int main()
{

    voisin v = {5, NULL};

    printf("%d\n", v.indice);
    return 0;
}

Output:
    5


Your problem seems to be the one explained by @greg.
Anyway, this is valid syntax:
// I define a named struct, and then a type based on it

struct sommet {
    int indice;
};

typedef struct sommet t_sommet;

This is valid syntax too:
// I define a named struct and a type (at the same time)

typedef struct sommet {
    int indice; // etc
} t_sommet;

This is valid syntax too:
// I directly define a type, based on an unnamed struct

typedef struct {
    int indice; // etc
} t_sommet;

In all cases, I'm using sommet as the name of the struct and t_sommet as the name of a (pseudo) new type, except in the last example, where I'm not naming the struct. Using the same name for the struct AND for the type, as you did, is perfectly valid but somehow confusing, at least for me. In fact, you don't need to define both: it's enough with the struct name or the typedef. Depending on your choice, you'll later reference the struct (or the type) using any of these variants:
struct sommet one;  // I'm using the struct name here (the struct keyword is required)
t_sommet another;   // I'm using the type name here

This is NOT valid syntax (the name of the new type is missing):
typedef struct sommet {
    int indice; // etc
};

